# UIDevice CFDictionaryGetValue error in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, multitasking, uidevice

I am checking:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]
```

in applicationDidEnterBackground. It is causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) signal. The stack trace shows that this is occurring internally in UIDevice, which is calling CFDictionaryGetValue.

Experimenting, calling:

```
CFDictionaryGetValue(NULL, "key");
```

results in the same error.

Any ideas? I have searched for documentation about accessing UIDevice while in the background and found nothing to indicate it should be a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
               [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
            

        });

Answer (score 0):

Calling (and logging) [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName] in applicationDidEnterBackground: works fine in my test. CFDictionaryGetValue(NULL, "key") will always crash, and has nothing to do with the problem you've encountered.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSString *systemName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
    if ( systemName )
        NSLog(@"%@", systemName);
    else
        NSLog(@"null systemName");
}
```